# Orbits for Borel subgroup action

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, group-actions

Consider the set of $n\times n$ upper-triangular matrices $\mathfrak b$. Let $B$ be the set of invertible $n\times n$ upper-triangular matrices. Consider the following action:

$$\begin{array}{rll}
(B\times B)\times \mathfrak b&\longrightarrow \mathfrak b\\
(b_1,b_2)\times b&\longmapsto &b_1bb_2^{-1}
\end{array}
$$

(1) Give a complete classification of orbits of this action.

(2) For each orbit $\mathfrak O$, consider the following action
$$\begin{array}{rll}
B\times \mathfrak O&\longrightarrow \mathfrak O\\
b_1\times b&\longmapsto &b_1bb_1^{-1}
\end{array}
$$
give a complete classification of orbits for this actions for each $\mathfrak O$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Have you made any partial progress?

Comment: Also, where did you encounter the problem? Is this a problem from a textbook? Do we have a reason to expect that the question has a nice answer?

Comment: It is not come from textbook. It is not going to have  nice answer.

Comment: @QiruiLi Hi! Did you manage to solve this question?